# best way to update ui thread in android

Tags: android, performance, ui-thread

I have an application that plays back video frame by frame.  This is all working.  however looking into performance issues and running traceview I noticed that there were a lot of calls to dispatch message, this was using a lot of cpu time.

As I looked at my app, I am using a handler to post a callback to the ui to display the current frame number.  When I removed this all the dispatchMessage calls in traceview are gone.

So my question is, what is the best way to update the ui from a worker thread without experiencing so much overhead?

**NOTE, this call is made about 30 times a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources stated are good approached depending on needs.  In my case it was a result of a couple minor things happening on the ui thread, mainly some simple transformations.  I moved all of this to my background thread so I was drawing a pre transformed bitmap.  This gave enough relief to the ui thread to resolve my problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
// declaration
BrightTimer brt;
Handler mHandler;
Runnable mUpdateResults;

// onCreate
mHandler = new Handler();
mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //  set value to the widget you wish to update when the thread is running
    }
};
int delay = 0; // delay for 1 sec.
int period = 60000; // repeat every 1 sec.

Timer timer = new Timer();

brt = new BrightTimer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(brt, delay, period);

// TimerClass
public class BrightTimer extends TimerTask
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: The above is what I am doing with the handler approach, the only difference is I am not posting updates at a fixed interval via 'timer' thread, I am executing them on an as needed basis.  The above would not work for me as I would skip frame updates, which wouldn't be desired.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely clear about your implementation but you could try these. If you are updating a view through your handler you could use this on the view itself to update it from a different thread.

post() : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)

The other thing you could try is using the runOnUIThread() available in the Activity class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Hope it helps.

Comment: These are great resources that go through the different ways to update the ui thread, I was updating correctly, but other things were causing my issues see my answer.